# Can't pass datas back from UIView Popover Dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, popover

I have set a "Show as popover" segue between a UIView (A) and another UIView (B) (embed in a Navigation Controller) activated on a button's clic.

i am trying to pass datas back from (B) to (A) when i dismiss it (i want to keep the popover animation on both ways).

I have tried many methods i found mostly here, on Stackoverflow, but as of now i never successfully retrieved my data on (A).

I tried Delegates and protocols as well as other simpler methods. The last in date is the following one:

- In (A), i just try to print the variable that should be storing the datas in ViewWillAppear :

```swift
class SearchBarsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var testValue:String = ""

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(testValue) // print is empty
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

}
```

- In (B), i dismiss the popover and try to send the datas back on a button clic :

```swift
class SearchFilterViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func DismissPopoverOnClic(_ sender: Any) {
            if let navController = presentingViewController as? UINavigationController {
                let presenter = navController.topViewController as! SearchBarsController
                presenter.testValue = "Test"
                print("success") //never called
            }
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

on (B) i'd like to set up some filter that i'd use on (A) to present search results in a tableview. But actually the testValue's value is always blank.

Comment: You Can use Unwind Segue For Get back to to A From the viewcontroller B .If you want i can make a sample project for you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oky so you can do it using unwind segue here is sample project :

[sample projecct](https://github.com/ekramramu/unwindSege)

process :

Add this method to `SearchBarsController` below `viewWillAppear`

```
@IBAction func unWindFromFilterViewController(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }
```

Than go to Storyboard and go to `SearchFilterViewController` and then cntrl + Drag from `DismissPopoverOnClic` to top of the exit button then select unWindFromFilterViewController .

[image: Drag button to this exit and select unWindFromFilterViewController]

Than this the `SearchFilterViewController` write this method for passing data

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? ViewController {
           destVC.testValue = "Test"

        }
    }
```

You will get your desired data back . thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm and is definitely the simplest method i found.

Answer (score 0):

When passing back data to a `viewController`, the most efficient way to implement it using `delegate`

```
protocol SearchFilterViewControllerDelegate {
    func setTextValue(string : String)
}
```

```
class SearchFilterViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate : SearchFilterViewControllerDelegate?


    @IBAction func DismissPopoverOnClic(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        delegate?.setTextValue(string : "Test Value")
    }
}
```

```
class SearchBarsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var filterViewController : SearchFilterViewController? 
    func popup() {
        // your pop up code and init filterViewController
        filterViewController.delegate = self **//without this line, the delegate will be nil, no nothing will happen.**
    }
}

extension SearchBarsController : SearchFilterViewControllerDelegate {
    func setTextValue(string : String) {
        print(string)
    }
}
```